# Do people actually use "ehrfürchtig!" to say awesome?

Tags: word-usage

Do people actually use "ehrfürchtig!" to say awesome or is it old in usage?

If not, then what would be more in common usage? 
I've heard mostly *toll, super, prima* but what else is possible?

Comment: It comes up when you search "awesome" on Leo.org but I've never heard it said. I've made the mistake of learning a word thinking it meant what the dictionary said only to be told you'd never hear that in real life.

Comment: Do **not** use dict.leo. I only take it as a fallback when I'm not satisfied with the results taken from prior research. I suggest using [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american-german/awesome?showCookiePolicy=true) and [Pons](http://de.pons.eu/übersetzung?q=awesome&l=deen&in=&lf=en). They both categorize the words and translations are spot on – most times. Further more, you should think of looking results up in a monolingual dictionary (Pons, Wiktionary) and do a back-translation and look what's the result.

Comment: What Em1 said. Do **not** use dict.leo. Their translations are often wrong, or just awful.

Comment: leo.org is still one of the better online dictionaries, and their community, in particular, is invaluable. If there's one dictionary you shouldn't use, it's dict.cc.

Comment: "ehrfürchtig" is never used in the sense of first-class etc. The adjectives are: toll, prima, Spitze, Klasse, super, and geil. The last word has a sexual meaning, too.

Comment: In fairness, leo.org also provides several perfectly serviceable translations for “awesome” and some reasonable translations for “ehrfürchtig”. The awesome <-> ehrfürchtig entry is a bit odd but you should be able to figure it out, even if all you had was leo.org.

Comment: awesome <-> ehrfürchtig is only as odd as awesome and awful sharing meaning in the cognate but mostly forgotten sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well first of all to me as a native German there is a clear difference between "ehrfürchtig" and awesome. I would rather translate ehrfürchtig with something like reverent or awestruck.

In my opinion you would rather use the following as a equivalent to awesome.

super, toll as you pointed out correctly but also "unglaublich" (unbelievable) and "wunderbar" (wonderful). Now as you notice both of them already have a translation. Still, in such cases though it heavily depends on the context, you can use words like "unglaublich" to describe something really awesome.

Lets say you are seeing an awesome landscape.

```
Das ist wirklich eine unglaubliche Landschaft.
```

Or some friend found a job after searching for quite a while: (Its so awesome you finally found a job!)

```
Es ist wirklich wunderbar, dass du endlich einen Job gefunden hast.
```

Well and last but not least lets not forget the colloquial ones:

```
"Hammer!", "Geil!", "Krass!" for example.
```

You wont hear those from everyone but they still exist.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: *Großartig* is another valid translation for *awesome*.

Comment: *"unglaublich"* kann auch mit *"incredible"* übersetzt werden. Dazu gibt es sogar einen Disney-Film ;) Mein persönlicher Liebling ist aber immer noch *"atemberaubend"*.

Comment: What is awesome then? I am using it for a role playing game (Nationstates: The Great Awesome Prussia is my nation :)) but I am using the words that are being told not to be used. Now, most of this is being used as filler for the post requirements.

Comment: `"Geil"` und `"Krass"` können noch mit dem Prefix `"End-"` gesteigert werden :)

Comment: @Snbdf awesome is quite generic I think, and also not something one would use for a real country. Großartig would be most fitting but is redundant because of Great=Groß (Das Große Großartige Preußen... meh!) So what kind of subtext are you looking for?  Threatening? Godlike? Strong? over the top silly? :)

Answer (score 7):

To chime in with the others and add another aspect:

Note that "ehrfürchtig" *never* means "awesome". It describes the reaction *to* something that is awesome, NOT the fact that it *is* awesome. Leo and any other dictionaries that say otherwise are plain wrong.

The correct German equivalent (in a purely lexical sense) would be "**ehrfurchtgebietend**" (i.e. "demanding/causing awe"). Usage-wise, however, this is absolutely not equivalent to the casual "awesome" in English.

Answer (score 3):

*ehrfürchtig* wouldn't be used as an exclamation, and I've actually never read it in that context, even in old literature.

The exclamation *Awesome!* would usually be translated as *Großartig!* or *Erstaunlich!*, while the latter is rather used in the context of *Amazing!*.

Answer (score -2):

Ich finde, am besten passt "fantastisch".;)